# CSS/HTML: Handling Fluid Layouts and Height?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, fluid-layout

Here's an example demonstrating this problem: 
http://jsfiddle.net/93twL/

Here's the code (same as the jsfiddle):

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>
            Heading
        </h1>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="left">
            <h3>
                Left
            </h3>
            <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis tortor ligula. Aenean sagittis ut nibh quis hendrerit. Proin tincidunt scelerisque feugiat. Duis nunc erat, accumsan sed diam in, vulputate rutrum velit. Etiam tincidunt pretium dolor, sit amet bibendum tortor congue pulvinar. Donec convallis mauris non nunc consectetur, eget auctor nisi volutpat. Vestibulum lobortis nunc non ullamcorper faucibus. Nulla convallis justo in turpis aliquet vehicula. Donec eget turpis tempor, ornare magna nec, rhoncus orci. Sed pharetra risus orci, eu facilisis diam interdum id. 
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <h3>
                Main
            </h3>

                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis tortor ligula. Aenean sagittis ut nibh quis hendrerit. Proin tincidunt scelerisque feugiat. Duis nunc erat, accumsan sed diam in, vulputate rutrum velit. Etiam tincidunt pretium dolor, sit amet bibendum tortor congue pulvinar. Donec convallis mauris non nunc consectetur, eget auctor nisi volutpat. Vestibulum lobortis nunc non ullamcorper faucibus. Nulla convallis justo in turpis aliquet vehicula. Donec eget turpis tempor, ornare magna nec, rhoncus orci. Sed pharetra risus orci, eu facilisis diam interdum id. 


                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis tortor ligula. Aenean sagittis ut nibh quis hendrerit. Proin tincidunt scelerisque feugiat. Duis nunc erat, accumsan sed diam in, vulputate rutrum velit. Etiam tincidunt pretium dolor, sit amet bibendum tortor congue pulvinar. Donec convallis mauris non nunc consectetur, eget auctor nisi volutpat. Vestibulum lobortis nunc non ullamcorper faucibus. Nulla convallis justo in turpis aliquet vehicula. Donec eget turpis tempor, ornare magna nec, rhoncus orci. Sed pharetra risus orci, eu facilisis diam interdum id. 
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis tortor ligula. Aenean sagittis ut nibh quis hendrerit. Proin tincidunt scelerisque feugiat. Duis nunc erat, accumsan sed diam in, vulputate rutrum velit. Etiam tincidunt pretium dolor, sit amet bibendum tortor congue pulvinar. Donec convallis mauris non nunc consectetur, eget auctor nisi volutpat. Vestibulum lobortis nunc non ullamcorper faucibus. Nulla convallis justo in turpis aliquet vehicula. Donec eget turpis tempor, ornare magna nec, rhoncus orci. Sed pharetra risus orci, eu facilisis diam interdum id. 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <h3>
                Right
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis tortor ligula. Aenean sagittis ut nibh quis hendrerit. Proin tincidunt scelerisque feugiat. Duis nunc erat, accumsan sed diam in, vulputate rutrum velit. Etiam tincidunt pretium dolor, 
            </p>
        </div>

        <footer id="footer">
            <h3>
                Footer
            </h3>
        </footer>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

html{
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px black;
}
h1{ 
    margin-top:0;
}
#container{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px black;
}

#header{
    min-height:12%;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: inherit;
}
#footer{
    min-height:10%;
    box-shadow: inherit;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
#left{
    float:left;
    box-shadow: inherit;
    width:24.5%;
    padding:0.5%;
    min-height:50%;
}

#main{
    float:left;
    box-shadow: inherit;
    width:48%;
    min-height:50%;
    padding:0.5%;
}

#right{
    float:left;
    box-shadow: inherit;
    width:24.5%;
    padding:0.5%;
    min-height:50%;
}
```

As seen in the example by looking at the borders, once the content goes above 100% heigtht, the content overflows. I'd rather have the element expand.

**To fix this, one would remove specifying the height. However, if there is no height specified then how am I supposed to control the height of all the content?(using percentages)** I need buttons, headers, footers and so on that need a height set to it. (Without HTML and BODY having a 100% height, no other elements will be able to set a height using percentages)

In case it is not clear, I am talking about a fluid layout where the height is given in **percentages**.

So is this even possible or should I just give this up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're after is a fluid width 100% and 100% height, so that the content vertically and horizontally expands. That is a tough thing and can't be done with css alone, flexbox might be able to do it, though I don't know. I saw it recently done with CSS and jQuery using a fixed height on both the header and footer, but the rest is fluid height and width:

**http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EsJHu**

I made it more responsive here: http://jsbin.com/momep/7/edit

CSS

```
/* Reset  */
* { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}


/* Sticky footer */
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#page {
    height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    min-height: 100%;
}
#sticky-footer-wrap {
    overflow: auto;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}
.site-main {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
.site-footer {
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
    clear: both;
}


/* Header  */
.site-header {
    height: 100px;
}

@media (min-width:992px) {
/* 3 columns */
#primary {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;  
    margin-left: 25%;
}
#secondary {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin-left:-75%;
}
#tertiary{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
}
}

/* Colours */
.site-header {
    background: #C5E0DC;
}
#primary {
    background-color: #F1D4AF;
}
#secondary {
    background-color: #ECE5CE;
}
#tertiary{
    background-color: #E08E79;
}
.site-footer {
    background: #774F38;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="page">
    <div id="sticky-footer-wrap">
        <header class="site-header">
            <h3>Header</h3>
        </header>
            <div class="site-main">
            <div id="primary">
            <h2>Primary content</h2>
            <h1>Layout Features</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>Header (fixed height)</li>
                <li>3 fluid columns</li>
                <li>100% or full height columns (jQuery)</li>
                <li>Sticky footer (fixed height)</li>
                <li>Correct source order of columns</li>
                <li>IE8 compatible (Modernizr)</li>
            </ul>
            </div>              
            <div id="secondary">
                <h3>Secondary content</h3>
            </div>
            <div id="tertiary">
                <h4>Tertiary content</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<footer class="site-footer">
    <h3>Footer (sticky)</h3>
</footer>
```

jQuery

```
// On page load
$(window).load(columnHeight);

// On window resize
$(window).resize( function () {
    // Clear all forced column heights before recalculating them after window resize
    $("#primary").css("height", "");  
    $("#secondary").css("height", "");
    $("#tertiary").css("height", "");
    columnHeight();
});

// Make columns 100% in height
function columnHeight() {
    // Column heights should equal the document height minus the header height and footer height
    var newHeight = $(document).height() - $(".site-header").height() - $(".site-footer").height() + "px";
    $("#primary").css("height", newHeight);
    $("#secondary").css("height", newHeight);
    $("#tertiary").css("height", newHeight);
}
```

Comment: Yeah it appears this doesn't seem possible without javascript... :( It's not quite what I was looking for though but still...

Comment: I've been at this since 99 and without actual tables, it's near impossible to make it work. I have one working great in FireFox but Chrome is not working, this is not the same as yours, but it's annoying.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace height with min-height: 100%. And at the end of your HTML add a div with css rule clear: both to clean up all the floating elements.

So it will look like this :

```
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>
            Heading
        </h1>
    </header>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="left">
            <h3>
                Left
            </h3>
            <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis tortor ligula. Aenean sagittis ut nibh quis hendrerit. Proin tincidunt scelerisque feugiat. Duis nunc erat, accumsan sed diam in, vulputate rutrum velit. Etiam tincidunt pretium dolor, sit amet bibendum tortor congue pulvinar. Donec convallis mauris non nunc consectetur, eget auctor nisi volutpat. Vestibulum lobortis nunc non ullamcorper faucibus. Nulla convallis justo in turpis aliquet vehicula. Donec eget turpis tempor, ornare magna nec, rhoncus orci. Sed pharetra risus orci, eu facilisis diam interdum id. 
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <h3>
                Main
            </h3>

                <p>
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis tortor ligula. Aenean sagittis ut nibh quis hendrerit. Proin tincidunt scelerisque feugiat. Duis nunc erat, accumsan sed diam in, vulputate rutrum velit. Etiam tincidunt pretium dolor, sit amet bibendum tortor congue pulvinar. Donec convallis mauris non nunc consectetur, eget auctor nisi volutpat. Vestibulum lobortis nunc non ullamcorper faucibus. Nulla convallis justo in turpis aliquet vehicula. Donec eget turpis tempor, ornare magna nec, rhoncus orci. Sed pharetra risus orci, eu facilisis diam interdum id. 


                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis tortor ligula. Aenean sagittis ut nibh quis hendrerit. Proin tincidunt scelerisque feugiat. Duis nunc erat, accumsan sed diam in, vulputate rutrum velit. Etiam tincidunt pretium dolor, sit amet bibendum tortor congue pulvinar. Donec convallis mauris non nunc consectetur, eget auctor nisi volutpat. Vestibulum lobortis nunc non ullamcorper faucibus. Nulla convallis justo in turpis aliquet vehicula. Donec eget turpis tempor, ornare magna nec, rhoncus orci. Sed pharetra risus orci, eu facilisis diam interdum id. 
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis tortor ligula. Aenean sagittis ut nibh quis hendrerit. Proin tincidunt scelerisque feugiat. Duis nunc erat, accumsan sed diam in, vulputate rutrum velit. Etiam tincidunt pretium dolor, sit amet bibendum tortor congue pulvinar. Donec convallis mauris non nunc consectetur, eget auctor nisi volutpat. Vestibulum lobortis nunc non ullamcorper faucibus. Nulla convallis justo in turpis aliquet vehicula. Donec eget turpis tempor, ornare magna nec, rhoncus orci. Sed pharetra risus orci, eu facilisis diam interdum id. 
            </p>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <h3>
                Right
            </h3>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas quis tortor ligula. Aenean sagittis ut nibh quis hendrerit. Proin tincidunt scelerisque feugiat. Duis nunc erat, accumsan sed diam in, vulputate rutrum velit. Etiam tincidunt pretium dolor, 
            </p>
        </div>

        <footer id="footer">
            <h3>
                Footer
            </h3>
        </footer>
    </div>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're attempting to do here, but how about this?

http://jsfiddle.net/9X8j2/

Only the CSS changed:

```
body{
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px blue;
}
h1{ 
    margin-top:0;
}
#container{
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px gray;
}

#header{
    min-height:12%;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    box-shadow: inherit;
}
#footer{
    min-height:10%;
    box-shadow: inherit;
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
}
#left{
    float:left;
    box-shadow: inherit;
    width:24.5%;
    padding:0.5%;
    min-height:50%;
}

#main{
    float:left;
    box-shadow: inherit;
    width:48%;
    min-height:50%;
    padding:0.5%;
}

#right{
    float:left;
    box-shadow: inherit;
    width:24.5%;
    padding:0.5%;
    min-height:50%;
}
```

I changed the color of the box shadows to tell them apart a little easier.

Removing most of the height attributes may be what you're looking for.. including removing the CSS on the HTML tag. At least now the container does not overflow the body.

Please let me know if this is at all helpful.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately this is only a part solution: By removing the height, the children elements will not be able to use the height-property with percentages. For example in this code, the min-height of the elements like #right have no effect. What I would want is the way to alter the height (using percentages as value) of elements as well.